# Can not add/edit post in wordpress because of timestamp problem

Tags: wordpress, datetime, timestamp

It doesn't let me add or edit products, it just makes a red border around the `time stamp`. There's no error in the `browser console`, and playing with the time doesn't help.

[image]

**What I've tried**:

- The Time zone was correct on the setting panel!
- To see if it was related to a plugin, I disabled all plugins, but it wasn't
- Eventually, I changed the theme, and I realized it wasn't the theme.

How can I fix this problem? why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By disabling the Chrome `spoof timezone` extension, which caused Wordpress timezone to go wrong, I was able to resolve this issue.

[image]